# how to addMarker in leaflet Map angular4

Tags: angular, leaflet

I add a leaflet Map in my application and I want to add a Marker to it using data from my database. When I try it manually it works but when I try to get data from the database I get these 2 errors:
Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
and
ERROR Type Error: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
I share my code in this plunker 
My map.component.ts

```html
import { MapService } from './../services/map.service';
import { park } from './../park';
import { ParkService } from './../services/park.service';
import { MessageService } from './../services/message.service';
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Component, NgZone, Injector, ApplicationRef, ComponentFactoryResolver, OnInit, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

import { icon, latLng, Layer, Map, marker, Marker, point, polyline, tileLayer } from 'leaflet';
import * as L from 'leaflet';




@Component({
  selector: 'map',
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map.component.css']
})
export class MapComponent implements OnInit {
  public homeChanged: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

   
  constructor(private router: Router,
    private _parkService: ParkService,
    private messageService: MessageService,
    private maps : MapService,
    private modalService: NgbModal,
    private zone: NgZone
  ) {

  }
  parks:park;


  ngOnInit() {
    // S'exécute après la création du composant. C'est le meilleur endroit où on peut initialiser les propriétés.

    this.getAllParks();
   // this._stockService.showAllStores().subscribe(data => this.store.id = this.parks.Equipment);



  }
lt:number;
lg:number;

  googleMaps = tileLayer('http://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}', {
    maxZoom: 20,
    subdomains: ['mt0', 'mt1', 'mt2', 'mt3'],
    detectRetina: true
  });

customCircleMarker = L.CircleMarker.extend({
  options: { 
     someCustomProperty: 'Custom data!',
     anotherCustomProperty: 'More data!'
  }
});
markers:Marker[];
markerData = [];
map:Map;

getAllParks() :  Marker[]{
  this._parkService
    .showAllParks()
    .subscribe(parks => {
      this.parks = parks;
      for(let park of parks)
      {
        this.lt = park.latitude ;
         this.lg = park.longitude;

      this.markerData=[this.lt, this.lg];

       for( var i =0 ; i< this.markerData.length; i++){
     this.markers.push(marker(this.markerData[i], { icon: this.createIcon() }))
      
  }


    }

   });
    return this.markers
}

//   markers: Marker[] = [
//     marker([ 35.80635, 10.6346 ], { icon: this.createIcon() }),
//     // marker([ 46, -121 ], { icon: this.createIcon() }),
//     // marker([ 47, -121 ], { icon: this.createIcon() }),
//     // marker([ 48, -121 ], { icon: this.createIcon() }),
//     // marker([ 49, -121 ], { icon: this.createIcon() })
//   ];
// lt:number;
// lg:number;
//   markerData: [number , number][]= [
    
//     [this.lt, this.lg],
//     [35.80635, 10.61376],
//     [35.8698, 10.5352]
//   ]

  // setMarkers():  Marker[]{
  //   for( var i =0 ; i< this.markerData.length; i++){
  //    this.markers.push(marker(this.markerData[i], { icon: this.createIcon() }))
      
  // }
  //   return this.markers;
  // }

  layers: Layer[] = [];


  options = {
    layers: [ this.googleMaps ],
    zoom: 11,
    center: latLng([ 35.8245, 10.61376 ])
  };
  


  createIcon() {
    return icon({
      iconSize: [ 25, 41 ],
      iconAnchor: [ 13, 41 ],
      iconUrl: 'assets/img/marker.png',

      //shadowUrl: 'assets/img/marker-shad.png'
    });
  }
  updateMarkers() {
    this.markers= this.getAllParks();
    this.zone.run(() => {
      this.layers = this.markers.filter((m: Marker) => this.map.getBounds().contains(m.getLatLng()));
    });
  }

  onMapReady(map: Map) {
    this.map = map;

    this.map.on('moveend', this.updateMarkers.bind(this));
    this.map.on('zoomend', this.updateMarkers.bind(this));

    this.updateMarkers();
  }
  addMarker() {
    var m = L.marker([35.80635, 10.61376]);
    m.bindTooltip('Angular 4 marker (PopupComponent)');
    m.bindPopup(null);
   
    //this.markersLayer.addLayer(m);
    return m;
}





}
```

and my map.component.html

```html
<div id="map"
leaflet
[leafletLayers]="layers"
(leafletMapReady)="onMapReady($event)"
(leafletMapReady)="($event)"
[leafletOptions]="options">
</div>
```

Comment: Your link is not working...

Comment: i put the code here

Answer (score 1):

The `push` error is because you didn't initialize your `markers` yet

```
markers:Marker[] = [];
```

The `filter` error is also because of this too, however it isn't the only thing wrong. Your `getAllParks()` method is doing asynchronous work and the `markers` will not be set until some point later, however you are treating the code synchronously and returning the `markers` right away. My point is that your calls to `getAllParks()` is not getting your `markers` that come back from the service, but rather the `markers` that are set before you call it.

The problem is that we don't know enough about your use cases to know what direction to point you in to get your code to work properly in relation to these other problems that will arise.

Comment: thank you the errors are gone but as you say the marker are not added ,Don't know how i fix it just i want to get my lat and long from the park table

Comment: @loulita I can try to help you out if you can provide more details above in what you are trying to do. I see that you have multiple pieces of info that you are holding onto (`parks`, `markers`, `layers`). Do you need a reference to each of those, or do you only need your `layers` property which is used in your template?

Comment: I have a park table contain latitude and longitude values just i want to bring them and put it in the Map